# Send notification to the admin when new custom post is submitted

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, wp-mail, notifications

I have a cpt called "auto" and i make a frontend form to create new post with "pending" status.
After the post submission i would receive an email with a notification of the new post.

```
function newpost_notify() {

  $mailadmin = 'xxx@domain.com';
  $subject = 'Subject';
  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";    
  $headers .= 'From: xxx <noreply@domain.com>' . "\r\n";
  $message = 'There\'s a new post.';

  wp_mail( $mailadmin, $subject, $message, $headers );
}

add_action( 'publish_post', 'newpost_notify', 10, 2 );
```

This is my code..but i didn't receive any email.

I would know if there's a difference between a "new post" and a "publish post", because i read something about the post status transition.

Thank you

Comment: If you read something about post status transition you should know, that you can shoot yourself in the foot very well with what you got there.

Comment: @flomei it would be more constructive to _explain_ the issues, rather than just make fun of them.

Comment: You´re right. For clarification: `publish_post` can really backfire at you, because it runs whenever a post/page/custom post type is saved. So you should not use it for sending mails. Using [Post Status Transitions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions), for example `pending_to_publish`, would be a better way, cause they are run only when a post/page is "really" published...

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. 
Now I think I understand.
But I'm not sure is necessary to use a post-status transition...because the post don't come from another status. 
I wish that the notification was sent when the post is created. There is the status "new" which I think is more appropriate. Correct me if I'm wrong, but you do not think is right "new_auto" {status}_{post_type}?

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, instead of an edit. It's OK to [answer your own question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), and you can accept it after 48 hours, so the question will not remain open and unanswered.

Comment: ok @Gabriel ..I'm beginning to understand how works here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT - SOLUTION

I got the solution using status 'new_to_pending' and adding the $auto object.

```
function newpost_notify( $auto ) {

  $mailadmin = 'xxx@domain.com';
  $subject = 'Subject';
  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";    
  $headers .= 'From: xxx <noreply@domain.com>' . "\r\n";
  $message = 'There\'s a new post.';

  wp_mail( $mailadmin, $subject, $message, $headers );
}

add_action( 'new_to_pending', 'newpost_notify', 10, 2 );
```

thanks to the constructive comments of @Rarst & @flomei

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does not work for me in 2021. I suspect that the action hook name(s) have changed.

Here's the updated solution that's working for me:

```
function newpost_notify( $auto ) {

  $mailadmin = 'xxx@domain.com';
  $subject = 'Subject';
  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";    
  $headers .= 'From: xxx <noreply@domain.com>' . "\r\n";
  $message = 'There\'s a new post.';

  wp_mail( $mailadmin, $subject, $message, $headers );
}

add_action( 'pending_auto', 'newpost_notify', 10, 2 );
```

**Note that the action name is dynamic, so you will need to adjust the first argument of `add_action` to match your custom post_type.** The format is {status}_{postType}.

Also note that the argument passed to the callback function is the post ID of the new post (not an instance of WP_Post).